# How to pin a URL to OS X Dock with a custom image?

Tags: macos, dock

I'd like to pin a URL to the Dock and have its icon be something meaningful or recognizable.

By default, the icon/shortcut is a generic spring icon, and in Yosemite it shows a globe.

[image]
[image]

How can I create or modify a docked URL shortcut to be the site's favicon or an image I choose?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

1. Move/drag the shortcut to the Desktop first
2. Find an image (on the web, etc.) Open it in Preview, Select All, and Copy.

   [image]
3. Open Get Info on your shortcut on the Desktop. Select the current icon at the top left of this window. It will highlight to be blue.

   [image]
4. Command-V to paste the image over top of the icon.
5. Close the properties window.
6. Drag the shortcut icon to the Dock. Note that items can only be dropped between the trash can and the black divider line.

Answer (score 2):

You can take it a step further too.  If you have several shortcuts you would like to keep handy, create a folder.  Using the same procedure as noted by [in the previous answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58258/120171) you can change the folder's icon to anything you wish as well and then pin that to your **Dock**.

- Create a **Folder** in a location of your choice (**Documents** is good)
- Add your weblinks
- Change the folder's icon in the same manner as [previously described.](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/58258/120171)
- Drag the new folder to your **Dock**
- Change the **Display as** and **View content as** to your liking.

[image: Links folder]

[image: Settings]

Set to **Display as... Folder** Otherwise you get a stack of icons... UGLY.

[image]

Comment: I would add a minor point, when you put it on the dock at the bottom you need to put it to the right of the little black line that is on the left of the trashcan and download folder. Basically you are creating a folder and thats where folders and files can be pinned to the dock. Great life hack though so thanks to the two posts above this one.

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a superior solution:
https://www.macintoshhowto.com/productivity/how-to-add-google-keep-to-osx-to-sync-your-notes-across-your-phones.html

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.