# Can you place a shortcut or a link to a website in the dock in osx?

Tags: dock, shortcut

Is there a way you can place a shortcut or a link to a website in the dock in osx ? Similar to how you can save a website to the homescreen of ios.

Id like to do this on 2 machines - one is on osx 10.9 and one is on 10.8.

Answer (score 5):

1. Select URL and drag it to your desktop.
2. Drag the newly created shortcut to your Dock*.

*Optional*:

3. If you want to add a custom image, there are [instructions in this Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/58251/how-to-pin-a-url-to-os-x-dock-with-a-custom-image) thread.

* In Yosemite, at least, it can only be placed on the right pane of the Dock.

Comment: Nice one, with extras :) that is a + from me. FYI it also works on Mavericks (placing it in the right part of the Dock)

Comment: The dock has a separator, left is applications, right are folder aliases.  The dock has worked this way for many versions of OS X.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Here are the steps:

1. Create a Bookmark (Chrome/Firefox) or Favorite (Safari) of the sites you want linked.
2. Open up the Bookmarks/Favorites bar, and locate the bookmark you just created.
3. Drag the bookmark with the mouse onto your Desktop.
4. Now drag the webloc that was created from your Desktop onto the dock.

Optional: If you don't want the link to live on your desktop, you can drag it into a different Finder folder. If you want the link to have a different icon, you can simply set a different icon in Finder.